# VSTS BuildClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync throws Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi exception

Tags: azure-devops, azure-api-management

I'm trying to automate build artifact download. The objective is to download a specific build artifact. When I call `BuildClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync`, it throws the following error

[image]

I am using the following code

```cs
        private static void DownloadBuildResults(Build StartedBuild, string ArtifactName)
        {
            //BuildArtifact drop = BuildClient.GetArtifactAsync(StartedBuild.Id, ArtifactName).Result; //get detiled info

            //Console.WriteLine("Build location: " + drop.Resource.DownloadUrl);

            //string dropFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}.zip", StartedBuild.Definition.Name, StartedBuild.BuildNumber);

            Stream zipStream = BuildClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync(79414, "abc").Result; //get content

            using (FileStream zipFile = new FileStream("abc.zip", FileMode.Create))
                zipStream.CopyTo(zipFile);
```

Please note that I **buildID** and **artifact name** is correct. I have double-checked these values. The above code example is taken from https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/blob/master/19.TFRestApiAppQueueBuild/TFRestApiApp/Program.cs

Is this a bug in the API/SDK? or Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the sample code if someone wants to give a try
GIST: https://gist.github.com/abhishekgoenka/9759256f995e7f7c9cbcb7872c8591c0

I get following error in code
[image]

Stack trace

```
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<HandleResponseAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClientBase.<GetArtifactContentZipAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Utils.Dashboard.FrmAzureDashboard.<BtnDownloadKHP_Click>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\code\MetaFXTools\ui\Utils\Dashboard\FrmAzureDashboard.cs:line 118
```

Answer (score 2):

I have hit the same issue as well.

What I have determined so far is that the call to GetArtifactContentZipAsync results in a 302 response from the server.

(The Location header in the response is along the lines of: https://artproduks1.artifacts.visualstudio.com/.../_apis/artifact/.../content?format=zip)

Inside of GetArtifactContentZipAsync is a call to httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() and this causes the error to be thrown as the library is not expecting a redirect to be returned.
It is possible to create the connection using: new VssConnection(uri, creds, new VssClientHttpRequestSettings{AllowAutoRedirect = true}), so that the redirect is followed, however this then errors with a different message indicating that an incorrect version has been sent to the server.

Comment: I ended up using `GetArtifactAsyc().Resource.DownloadUrl` along with a `HttpClient` request to download the pipeline artifact. See https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample for how to authenticate the `HttpClient` request.

Answer (score 1):

I got to know the reason of the exception being thrown when calling this API.
In the pipeline if you are using the "Publish build artifacts" to publish the artifacts, the API will work fine. Whereas if you use "Publish pipeline artifact" task, the API will return 302 ("Found").

Microsoft currently has no workaround for this issue and I would suggest you to use either HttpClient or WebClient to download the artifacts.

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted, but I just confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in the API/SDK? or Am I doing something wrong?

I can confirm the [code from ashamrai](https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/blob/master/19.TFRestApiAppQueueBuild/TFRestApiApp/Program.cs) is correct.(I tested it with my VS2019 16.6 and it works well.) And there's could be something with the values of your variables. I suggest you use `try-catch` to call the `DownloadBuildResults` function so that you can share detailed error message here. I just changed a bit from your code above:

```
class Program
{
    
    static readonly string TFUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganizationName/";
    static readonly string UserPAT = "YourPAT";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int buildId = 832; // update to an existing build definition id
            string artifactName = "drop"; //default artifact name
            ConnectWithPAT(TFUrl, UserPAT);
            Stream zipStream = BuildClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync(buildId, artifactName).Result; //get content
            using (FileStream zipFile = new FileStream(@"C:\MySite\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
                zipStream.CopyTo(zipFile);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine("Detailed Info: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Stack:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

**So you need to make sure:**

1.You have a valid PAT which hasn't expired yet, and this PAT has the access to build artifact. Then directly enter the pat in  `static readonly string UserPAT = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";`. It should be `"PAT"` instead of `"<PAT>"`.

2.The URL(TFUrl) only needs OrganizationName as part of it.

3.Make sure you choose the correct artifact name.

4.Distinguish the difference between `BuildID` and `BuildDefinitionID`.

- You can see `buildDefinitionID` when editing the pipeline:

[image]

- You can see `BuildID` when checking the pipeline run results in web portal:

[image]

You should use the `BuildID` as input.

5.Also, the build you run(BuildID) should have the artifact published:

[image]

Your pipeline should have [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task. Check the log and make sure something is published, the folder to be published can't be empty.

6.Since you're only testing the code by Download artifact function, make sure you queue/run the build successfully before your run the code. (Wait for the end of the pipeline run.)

Comment: Thanks. I have verified that BuildID and PAT tokens are correct because other operations on SDK are working fine.

Error message is in question description. I am trying on VS2017 with .NET 4.8. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm using VS2019 while I don't think it's the main cause of the issue. Could you share a minimal sample project via github link so that we can check it directly for you? (Delete the core code and replace the personal info like PAT，URl with `***` to protect your Personal data)

Comment: I have updated the sample in question description.

GIST: https://gist.github.com/abhishekgoenka/9759256f995e7f7c9cbcb7872c8591c0

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks for the repo, I would check it later and let you know if I have any update :)

Comment: @Abhishek Your sample looks a bit different from the original sample in your question. Maybe you forget to add `.result` in the line throwing the error in your github sample. Try hard-coding the parameters like this:        `Stream zipStream = await BuildClient.GetArtifactContentZipAsync("MyProjectName", MyBuildId, "MyArtifactName").Result;` Also make sure all the nuget packages are latest version.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion. But still, I get the same error. All the parameters of `GetArtifactContentZipAsync` are correct because `BuildClient.GetArtifactAsync` is complete without any error with the same params. I have also copied full error stack trace in the issue description

Comment: I again tested the sample code in a .net 4.8 console project in VS2017, with all the nuget packages latest versions. My code sample works well. Have you really tried my code sample without modifying it?

Comment: ...Quite strange, how about creating a new test organization, a new test project and new Full access pat to test the code.

Comment: That would be a big work. I got some workaround. I will continue with that. Thanks for your time and effort.